# Delete obsolete / irrelevant values from SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL table which holds discounts per quantity per user. Now over time as sales people are handing out additional discounts, some other lines become obsolete. As you can see in my example below, recently someone gave this user a discount of 30% for every quantity (per 1), which makes most of the others obsolete, and from this point on it does not make sense to present that user with a list of discounts for all those other quantities.

(This is a consolidated table, where the actual discounts are coming from several other systems, so I cannot fix this at the source(s)).

Temp SQL Table with 2 columns (qty, discount)

```
qty  discount(%)
1    5
1    30       <-- makes all the others obsolete
5    20
25   25
50   28
100  30
250  40       <-- except this one
```

I'm looking for a query to clean up efficiently. I have been play with a loop, and with CTE. The loop worked, but that feels really slow/bad. With CTE i didn't manage to come up with the right query code.

The result i'm looking for is:

```
qty  discount(%)
1    30      
250  40
```

Here is some quick code for the table and test values https://rextester.com/ELW23373

Comment: what are obsolete value in Table according to you ?Can you explain ?

Comment: Obsolete are the ones I didn't mark (<--) in the original set. So those still have to be in the desired result set. In other words, those who are ruled out by the 2 left in the result set are obsolete.

Comment: No bro, why they are obsolete ? What is rule to recognize it as obsolete ?

Comment: The others are obsolete because there is already a higher discount for a lower quantity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply your logic with EXISTS in the DELETE statement:

```
delete t1 from table1 t1
where exists (
  select 1 from table1
  where 
    (minqty = t1.minqty and discount > t1.discount)
    or 
    (minqty < t1.minqty and discount >= t1.discount)
)
```

For the efficiency of this code you have to test it.
See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=7c44dd8a4086c4eb050dd27697f1d360).
Results:

```
> minqty | discount
> -----: | -------:
>      1 |       30
>    200 |       40
```

Answer (score 0):

> there is already a higher discount for a lower quantity

So there must be some formula to find this . What are they according to you ?

Also you must be having any identity/unique column in this column where you identify each row uniquely.

```
create table  #t (id int identity(1,1), qty decimal(5,2), discount decimal(5,2))
insert into #t values
(1  ,  5),(1 ,30),(5, 20),(25,25)
,(50,   28),(100,  30),(250,  40)  ;

with CTE as
(
Select *
,case when qty>1 then (qty/discount) else discount end NewCol 
from #t
)


delete from #t   where id not in (

select top 2 id from cte c 
order by newcol desc
)
select * from #t
drop table #t
```